# Unable to start program after setting CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY in CMAKE

Tags: c++, cmake

In my `CMakeLists.txt` I set `set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)` so that the binary file gets set to the `/bin` directory in the top level of my project.

However, now when I press "Build and Run" I get the following error:

```
Unable to start program
/long/path/to/build/release/ALL_BUILD path

The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I think this it because the binary is moved after it is built.  Is there a way to update the Visual Studio's knowledge of the file path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ALL_BUILD is not a runnable target by itself. It simply builds all targets that are not explicitly excluded from it. You should find the target for an executable that you’d like to run and and select `Set as StartUp Project` via a right-click menu.

Comment: When you load a solution, the default startup project is shown in bold in the solution explorer pane.  I think VS simply picks the first one when you first load a solution and this is often the "ALL BUILD" project in a CMake generated project.